# 25k site analytics are off by a day

Tags: bug, privileges, site-statistics

Users with 25k rep can see [site analytics](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/site-analytics).  Moderators also have a (more-detailed) view of site analytics.

Today I was looking at the moderator traffic graphs and saw some interesting spikes that I wanted to share with the community.  So I went over to the 25k view to take the following screen shot (which I then annotated):

[image]

Then I happened to notice that the 25k view provides mouse-over info on individual points on the graph -- *and they're all a day early*.  That very-interesting spike on Erev Yom Kippur (Tuesday, Oct 11) shows up in the 25k graph marked Monday, Oct 10.

How do I know that it's the 25k graph that's wrong?  Because all those weekly low points -- which should show up as Saturdays -- are showing up as Fridays.  Many of our users *and* visitors aren't ever online on Shabbat; our weekly traffic dips are definitely on UTC Saturdays, not UTC Fridays.

<sup>The existence of any traffic on UTC Saturday shouldn't be seen as a negative reflection on anybody.  First off, we're a worldwide community and there are parts of Saturday that aren't Shabbat in most places.  Second, we're here for the whole Internet, not just the subset that is Shabbat-observant Jews.</sup>